# White space to the right side of my header/navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, header-files

When i scroll to the right the header/navbar has a white space that just goes on,with the size of my pages contents.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn2v5.png)

ive set the width to 100% it doesnt change anything,heres the css piece

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #0288D1 ;
    color: white;
    padding:0rem 4rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;

}
```

heres the jsx file(its a react website)

```
       <nav>

       <div className="logo">
       <img src={TMElogo} alt=""/>
         </div>
         <h4>TME</h4>
        <div className='menu' onClick={() => {
            setMenuOpen(!menuOpen)
        }}>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
        <ul className={menuOpen ? "open" : ""}>
            <li>
            <NavLink to="/">HOME</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
            <NavLink to="/hummingbird">HUMMINGBIRD</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
            <NavLink to="/about">ABOUT</NavLink>
            </li>
        </ul>

         </nav>
```

ive tried to look for any unwanted padding , and ive checked if theres any width overriding this in any other sections,ive also tried the !important(i know its not good practice) didnt work. what could be the problen?

Comment: Can you provide a working example via jsfiddle or other code playground?
Your CSS rules look fine. It's hard to tell from the screenshot but it looks like you have an element (like the footer) pushing it's contents outside of the bodies fixed width.

Comment: Most probably you have an HTML élément in your page (footer..) that is largeur than 100vw. Set max -width :100vw; to some others suspected elements. Pls provide your code for more help

Comment: https://github.com/IrisThuo/HUMMINGBIRD/tree/main/src